# x86 assembly practice about graphics

Tags: graphics, assembly, x86

I'm trying to answer this practice question:
Write a code segment that draws an X on the whole screen, using XGA frame buffers.

All i know is that you have to increment each x and y pixel by 1 to get a diagonal line.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for resources on how to accomplish the drawing, you can look at [this](http://lordgalbalan.tripod.com/s_Homepage_Tutorial.htm), [this](http://www.wagemakers.be/english/doc/vga) or [this](https://sites.google.com/site/pratiktambe/graphics1) (if you like really bright colored text...). however, the point of a practice question (or homework) is for one to do ones own research.